# Counter example on Stinespring Dilation Theorem

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis

I've been trying to figure out what the calculations in between were when Stinespring in his counter example shows that a positive map is not necessarily completely positive.

I've attached the link of the paper here. 
https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1955-006-02/S0002-9939-1955-0069403-4/S0002-9939-1955-0069403-4.pdf
The counter example states:$A$ be the algebra of $n\times n$ matrices with complex entries. Denote $e_{ij}$ the matrix with 1 in the $i$th row and $j$th coloumn and zeros elsewhere. He says that the $e_{ij}$'s form a basis for the vector space $A$. Then define a linear function $\mu$ to be a matrix whose $(r,s)$th entry is $(r-j)(s-i)$ . Now if $\mu$ is positive, for $A=(a_{ij})\geqq0$ be an $n\times n $ amtrix and $x= \begin{bmatrix}x_{1}\\\vdots \\x_{n}\end{bmatrix}$ be any vector. then $(\mu(A)x,x)=\sum_{i,j,r,s}a_{ij}(r-j)(s-i)x_r\overline{x}_s$=$\sum_{i,j}(a_{ij})(\sum_{r}(r-j)x_r)(\sum_{s}(s-i)\overline{x_s})\geqq0$ since $A \geqq 0$.
He later goes on to show that $\mu$ is not completely positive and to show that he proves that $\mu^{(n)}$ is not positive. $E$ is an element of $A^{(n)}$ whose $(i,j)$th entry is the matrix $e_{ij}$. Its easily seen that $E \geqq 0$. But $\mu^{(n)}(E)$ is not $\geqq 0$ for $\sum_{i,j,r,s}(r-j)(s-i)\delta_{ir}\delta_{js}=\sum_{i.j}(i-j)(j-i)\leq0$. I'm confused with the computation part for $\mu^{(n)}$.

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me understand this counter example. Thank you!

Comment: Please spell out the example to make your post self-contained, and explain what your problems are in understanding it.

Comment: @MaoWao Hi, I updated my question!